# Retrieve specific child from Firebase Realtime database into the RecyclerView - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm quite new to firebase and android world. I want to retrieve only specific groups in which the current logged in user has joined.

[**Here is my Firebase realtime database structure**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/linrG.png)

However, all the users who logged in are displayed with all the groups exist in the database:

[**My app screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUHxF.jpg)

I tried to filter the output inside the `onBindViewHolder` method of `FirebaseRecylerAdapter` but it dont seem to be working :

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final GroupChatViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Group model) {

    final String groups = getRef(position).getKey();

    final String retGroupName = groups.toString();

    RootRef.child("Groups").child(retGroupName).child("Users").child(currentUser.getUid())
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        // If current user exist in that group
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            holder.txtGroupName.setText(retGroupName);

            //  Retrieve groupCreatedBy
            RootRef.child("Groups").child(retGroupName).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String retGroupCreatedBy = dataSnapshot.child("groupCreatedBy").getValue().toString();

                    //  Find username of the group creator
                    RootRef.child("Users").child(retGroupCreatedBy).child("profilename")
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                holder.txtGroupCreatedBy.setText("Group created by: " + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
        });
}
```

Here are my full codes. I implement all the process including the onBindViewHolder in a fragment class as shown below:

```
public class GroupChatFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    private RecyclerView chatList;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_group_chat, container, false);

        chatList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_chat_list);
        chatList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_chat);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Group> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Group>()
                .setQuery(RootRef.child("Groups"), Group.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Group, GroupChatViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Group, GroupChatViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final GroupChatViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Group model) {
...
}
        };

        chatList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    public static class GroupChatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtGroupName, txtGroupCreatedBy;

        public GroupChatViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtGroupName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.group_name_display);
            txtGroupCreatedBy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.group_createdby_display);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is expected result?

Comment: Can you highlight on the image?

Comment: We need a highlight in the database not in device.

Comment: @AlexMamo oops. here u go https://ibb.co/sKz7j0z . For example, for user i highlighted red, i want him to be displayed with only the groups i highlighted with yellow :)

Comment: And you want to get the names that is highlighted in yellow?